# Automating Sybase user creation

Tags: sql, sap-ase

Im trying to automate and creation of users with variabels.

```
declare @userid CHAR(8), @username CHAR(100), @role char(13), @password 
char(8)
SELECT @userid = "sas99887"
SELECT @username = "TEST"
SELECT @role = (@userid + "_role")
SELECT @password = "testpass"

create role @role
```

But it get a invalid syntax on @role on the last line
This is on a Sybase ASE server

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code:

```
declare @userid CHAR(8), @username CHAR(100), @role char(13), @password 
char(8), @cmd varchar(200)
SELECT @userid = "sas99887"
SELECT @username = "TEST"
SELECT @role = (@userid + "_role")
SELECT @password = "testpass"
select @cmd = "create role " || @role
exec (@cmd)
```